# Unknown option: --glue com.app.saf.glue.mf

Tags: jmeter, cucumber-java

I have used OS Process Sampler in my jmeter test plan

> Command java

```
Value

    -jar
    test-automation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    classpath:features/mf
    --glue com.app.saf.glue.mf
    --tags @LOANSETUP
```

When I run the test plan, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unknown option: --glue com.app.saf.glue.mf
            at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:148)
            at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:85)
            at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:78)
            at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:70)
            at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
            at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

> My Jmeter version is 3.2

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770706/unable-to-run-cucumber-feature-feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your configuration to:

```
-jar
test-automation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
classpath:features/mf
--glue 
com.app.saf.glue.mf
--tags 
@LOANSETUP
```

Comment: The configuration I have shared above,The Command Arg,and The Value parameters.